# Exiting on all errors in SWI Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Is there a way to make SWI Prolog exit on any syntax or parse errors? I'm writing tests and running them automatically, and I don't always notice the error messages if I have syntax errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean source file compilation errors, the `load_files/2` predicate misses an option to stop on first error. A possible solution is to define the `message_hook/3` predicate to call `abort/0` or `halt/1` in the case of a syntax error. Something like:

```
:- multifile user:message_hook/3.

user:message_hook(syntax_error(Culprit), _, _) :-
    % maybe print Culprit for some debugging information
    abort.
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, with `consult/1` and `ensure_loaded/1`.  I found it necessary to use `:- initialization(ensure_loaded(some_file)).` instead of just `:- ensure_loaded(some_file).`, otherwise the hook didn't get called (SWI 7.2.3). Also, the SWI docs for [`message_hook/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=message_hook/3) say that it must be defined as dynamic as well as multifile.